# NativeWindow not Working?

Tags: actionscript-3

I´m trying to simple make an aplication on AIR for desktop with the window on top.

It seems simple as :

```
debug.text = "start";

stage.nativeWindow.alwaysInFront=true;
stage.nativeWindow.activate();

debug.text = "done";
```

No errors on compiler, window will not get on top of others , and code after this lines not called....

I´m using Flash Professional CC and AIR 3.4 (Just downloaded this morning...)

Anyone knows what´s not correct !?
Can you help me !?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to keep a nativewindow on top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088160/how-to-keep-a-nativewindow-on-top)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I published it to a native installer with captive runtime, installed it on my computer and ran it. The window stays on top of other windows.

Here's a video of the final EXE running after it was installed. You can see the windows can't get on top of it:

http://www.ertp.com/tmp/ontop.mp4